# Public transportation between Agrigento to Syracuse

Tags: trains, public-transport, italy, buses, sicily

I want to travel from Agrigento to Syracuse. I saw possibilities in Trenitalia but despite the distance being short, it takes more time due to multiple connections. Is there convenient (and cheaper) public transportation between these two cities?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been to Agrigento in 25+ years but back then there were buses to quite a few places from Agrigento. Although we took the train from Palermo to Agrigento, we ended up going back by bus, more convenient and more choices.

Answer (score 2):

Rome2Rio suggests [a 4h50m bus journey](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Agrigento/Siracusa-Italy) from Agrigento to Siracusa via Catania as your cheapest and fastest option:

[image: Rome2Rio Agrigento to Siracusa search results]

Buses run several times a day and are operated by [SAIS Trasporti](https://www.saistrasporti.it/), whose website details the itineraries and costs of all the tickets.

Alternatively, you can choose a 5h regional train journey via Caltanissetta. This itinerary is available once per day. See [the Trenitalia website](https://www.trenitalia.com/it/treni_regionali.html) for options and bookings.

Finally Blablacar is a very popular car-sharing service, that works fine in Italy.